# Django upload Photo via Httpie

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, httpie

I'm using DRF 2.3.13 , I want to upload photos by typing from terminal, so I use Httpie.

But I got **MultiValueDict: {}** ,  **empty**.

Am I missing the **headers="multipart/form-data"** ??

If true, so how to set the headers in Httpie??

Ex: I've sent it , but still get empty.

```
http -f -a username:password localhost:8000/photo/ FILES="path_to_image" author="AUTHOR" -h {'Content-Type':"multipart/form-data"}
```

tks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http -f -a username:password :8000/photo/ FILES@path_to_image author="AUTHOR"
```

See [Request items](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#request-items) and [File upload forms](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#file-upload-forms) for more details.